# A question on Grassmannian manifolds and universal line bundles

Tags: manifolds, vector-bundles, smooth-manifolds, grassmannian

> **Problem.** Fix an $ n \in \mathbb{N} $. Is it true that there exists a $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ such that every smooth complex line bundle over a smooth $ n $-dimensional real manifold is the pullback of the tautological line bundle $ \gamma_{k}^{1} $ over $ \mathbb{CP}^{k} = \mathbf{Gr}_{1} \! \left( \mathbb{C}^{k + 1} \right) $? (**Note:** The pullback is assumed to be smooth as well.)

I do know that:

> By the Whitney Embedding Theorem, we can find a fixed $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ such that every smooth complex line bundle over a smooth $ n $-dimensional real manifold is the (smooth) pullback of the universal rank-$ 1 $ **sub-bundle** $ E^{1} $ of the tautological $ k $-bundle $ \gamma_{1}^{k} $ over $ \mathbf{Gr}_{k} \! \left( \mathbb{C}^{k + 1} \right) $.

**My guess:** The problem would have an affirmative answer if two things were true:

1. There exists a diffeomorphism $ \phi: \mathbf{Gr}_{1} \! \left( \mathbb{C}^{k + 1} \right) \to \mathbf{Gr}_{k} \! \left( \mathbb{C}^{k + 1} \right) $.
2. We can arrange for $ \phi $ to satisfy $ \gamma_{k}^{1} = {\phi^{*}}(E^{1}) $.

The first point seems plausible and might be a well-known fact. However, I am doubtful about the second point.

Thanks to anyone willing to take a stab at this!

Comment: Yes, both of those things are true. The diffeomorphism is given by taking the dual vector space.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks! Yes, I think I just saw something over at [The Manifold Atlas Project](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Grassmann_manifolds) that confirms what you’ve just said.